# zsh: command not found: create-react-app (what does this mean?)

Tags: reactjs, terminal, macos-big-sur

why is this occurring? I've tried to set my path variable correctly but maybe I did it wrong and hope that's the reason zsh can't find the command "create-react-app" after installing it. I have very little experience in the terminal and am hoping someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the command line you have to run `npx create-react-app` (for npm)

This is because when packages are installed globally, they are still just plain JavaScript. You need the `npx` command to run the installed package's code.

Comment: Bingo Bango! This solution fixed my issue. Thank you for the solution and explanation of the `npx` command.